Is reverting to the macOS 13 keyboard layout switcher still possible on Sequoia?
This answer explains how to revert to the macOS 13 keyboard layout switcher on macOS 14:
Removing language icon from input fields after upgrading to macOS Sonoma
Is this still possible on macOS 15?

Motivation:
I regularly use several (more than two) keyboard layouts and I am looking to restore the following features when switching layouts with a shortcut key:

Invoking the shortcut a single time should toggle responsively between the last two layouts (ideally without showing any UI on screen).
Invoking it multiple times should cycle through all layouts in order, starting from the current layout (ideally with showing the list of layouts).
The system should be highly responsive to using the shortcut. It should be possible to switch layout, type a special character, then switch back, all under a second, without ever having to pause typing.

As I recall, the macOS 14 switcher failed on all three points. It limited my productivity enough that I do not dare update to macOS 15 until I get confirmation that I can revert to the old layout switcher (or that the new one works better).

Could you list the layouts you need?  I have my doubts you can get the responsiveness you want from the usual shortcuts, perhaps there is another way

@TomGewecke Does it matter which ones they are? I have 7 layouts installed, of which I regularly use 6 (my own language, my country's language, the language of the country where I live, my wife's language, English, and Greek for quicker math entry). The macOS 13 switcher is very responsive.

On my test install of Sequoia, the input switchers (globe/Fn or control space/control option space seem pretty responsive, but I have a newer M3 imac.  Have you already tried  https://github.com/hatashiro/kawa ?

@TomGewecke Thanks for testing this, and also for the link to a potential workaround if it turns out that macOS 15 broke this definitively. Does the new switcher support switching between the last two layouts if more than two layouts are installed? Or does it only cycle, without remembering the last layout?
